What's the meaning of various bot personalities' ELO ratings on Chess.com?
Chess.com has various bot "personalities" with their ELOs listed. But how should we interpret these ratings, given that the bots play instantly, and humans probably can't?

Possible duplicate : https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/7690/how-does-a-chess-engine-mimic-an-elo-rating
